# How to do google sign-in from an Android WebView and after successful sign-in redirect back to the home website?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, google-signin

I have an android app that uses a webview to render a website that has a google log-in and a facebook log-in. The problem is that when i do the google or facebook login, it opens a mobile browser and after successful login it does not go back to the app, it stays in the browser. I want it  to go to the app. It doesnot matter the login page opens in the webview itself or it opens in the browser. But after successful login it should redirect back to the home website in the app. i have tried rendering the login page in the webview itself but after logging in it stucks in a page.

I have added the INTERNET permission i the manifest

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView myWebView;
    WebView myPopedWebView;
    WebSettings myWebSettings;
    FrameLayout mContainer;
    String HOME_URL = "https://www.something.com";
    String HOME_URL_PREFIX = "www.something.com";
    Context mContext;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CookieManager cm = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cm.setAcceptCookie(true);

        myWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        myWebSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        mContainer = findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);

        myWebView.loadUrl(HOME_URL);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new customWebViewClient());
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new customWebChromeClient());

        myWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        myWebSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        myWebSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        myWebSettings.setUserAgentString(myWebSettings.getUserAgentString().replace("; wv", ""));

        mContext = this.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public class customWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
            Log.d("Loading url", url);

            if (host.equals(HOME_URL_PREFIX)) {

                if (myPopedWebView != null) {
                    myPopedWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mContainer.removeView(myPopedWebView);
                    myPopedWebView = null;
                }
                return false;
            }
            if (host.equals("www.facebook.com") || host.equals("www.accounts.google.com")) {
                return false;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }

        @Override public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
        }
    }

    public class customWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog, boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {

            myPopedWebView = new WebView(mContext);

            myPopedWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            myPopedWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            myPopedWebView.setWebChromeClient(new customWebChromeClient());
            myPopedWebView.setWebViewClient(new customWebViewClient());
            myPopedWebView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport)resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(myPopedWebView);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            return true;
        }

        @Override public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            Log.d("onCloseWindow", "closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code that requests the facebook (or google) account login with login callback. Here's what you can do:

1. Either code the login capability(along with login callback url configuration) in the website that has your login with facebook or google buttons.
2. or, you can add facebook and google sign-in (auth) sdks in your android app and handle the login and callback in your app (writing java/kotlin code).

You can choose either of the two approaches, you can easily find tutorials online on how to integrate facebook sdk in web (approach 1) or android (approach 2).

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks Vikas. The option number 2, will it work with webview? because my login page is in the website. i have seen the documentation, there they have written that we should have a facebook button for that.

Comment: Yes, it will work. But your token and all will be received by your server as callback will be received by your website.